# How do I resolve this error? ERROR: failed to create deliver client: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded

Tags: ubuntu, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm attempting to build my first network using HyperLedger Fabric and I've run into an error that I'm stuck on. I'm on the **Create & Join** section in this tutorial: [Build Your First Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOmkJ.jpg)

The error arises with this console command:

```
peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

I receive this error: *"Error: failed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.example.com:7050: failed to create 
new connection: context deadline exceeded"*

Here's a screenshot of my console error and the logs of the failing Orderer:

[image]

Would someone kindly assist me on fixing this error so that my peer will connect to the orderer client? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you add the fabric version to you question?

One of the problems could be that you have an old version of the example and the example downloaded the newest version of the fabric (v1.2) The **cryptogen tool**, can generate different metadata that could make the orderer to break and stop the container.

My suggest is to check if the cryptogen version that you are using is the one contained in your downloaded image of your example. If you had run lot of tests, clean all images and containers, that always help.

If nothing of that works, I wrote a tutorial based on the basic-network example and how to run it in multiple hosts, maybe you can take some information from there.

https://medium.com/1950labs/setup-hyperledger-fabric-in-multiple-physical-machines-d8f3710ed9b4

Please, feel free to ask, if you have doubts!

Answer (score 6):

Let me help you. I meet the same problem yesterday, and I solve it today in Mac environment (10.14.6).

1) Clear docker containers, images, and volumes:

docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)

docker rmi -f $(docker images)

docker volume prune

2) Clear the network (bring the network down) and re-run the *up* command:

./byfn.sh down

./byfn.sh -m generate

./byfn.sh up

3) Re-install the platform-specific binaries and config files:

- Open terminal
- Go to your designated directory or your *fabric-samples*
- Run the following command:

  *curl -sSL website | bash -s 1.2.0*

4) Update docker and docker-compose to the latest version

Then run them again:

./byfn.sh

./byfn.sh -m generate

./byfn.sh up

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need just to set `CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED` to true

```
CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
```