# How to get orderer logs | amazon managed blockchain

Tags: amazon-web-services, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, aws-cli, amazon-managed-blockchain

I setup hyperledger fabric in [amazon managed blockchain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/managementguide/managed-blockchain-get-started-tutorial.html). I can get peer node logs, CA logs, chaincode logs. I do not know how to get orderer logs. That is required to fix [this issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63041856/docker-exec-cli-peer-channel-create-failed-to-create-new-connection-context-d)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the orderer logs for AMB. To troubleshoot connectivity issue, try to perform a telnet against the orderer address and port